# Ansible: playbook-wide role_names

Tags: ansible

I use following condition to check whether certain role is present: `{% if "openmap" in role_names %}`. However it looks like `role_names` contains only role names that are executed on the current host. I came to this conclusion because I have following code in my `nginx.conf.j2`:

```
...
    {% if "monitoring" in role_names %}
        # monitoring proxying if the role is enabled
        location = /monitoring {
         proxy_pass http://{{ groups['monitoring_server'][0] }}:{{ external_grafana_port | int + group_port_offset | int }};
    }
    {% endif %}
...
```

and that part is skipped despite the fact that my `yaml` file that I run with `ansible-playbook` has this:

```
...
- hosts: monitoring_server
  become: yes
  roles:
    - role: monitoring
...
```

I would like to check whether certain role is present in the whole playbook, even though it will not be executed on the current host but rather on another one. How can I do it?

Comment: According to [the docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html), `role_names` should contain the names of all the active roles in the current play (not just for the current host). Can you show us how you're testing this?

Comment: @larsks - I have updated my question as per your request. Thank you!

Comment: I apologize, but something is still not clear. Is that template you show applied by the `monitoring` role? Because *every* host involved in that play should have `monitoring` in `role_names`.

Comment: @larsks: no, the template above is part of `frontend` role, not `monitoring`. The idea here is to enable `nginx` proxying to `grafana` (that runs on another (non-frontend) host) if `monitoring` role is enabled...